# Understanding homotopy t-structure

Tags: reference-request, stable-homotopy, motivic-homotopy, t-structure

The following question came up while reading Hoyois' 
[From algebraic cobordism to motivic cohomology](http://www.degruyter.com/view/j/crelle.2015.2015.issue-702/crelle-2013-0038/crelle-2013-0038.xml).

Let $S$ be a Noetherian scheme of finite Krull dimension and let $SH(S)$ denote the homotopy category of symmetric $\mathbb{P}^1$-spectra in pointed simplicial presheaves on $\mathbf{Sm}/S$. Denote by $SH(S)_{\geq d}$ the subcategory of $SH(S)$ generated under homotopy colimits and extensions by the $\Sigma^{p,q}\Sigma^\infty X_+$ for $X\in\mathbf{Sm}/S$ and $p-q\geq d$. Lurie's results show that $SH(S)_{\geq 0}$ is the non-negative part of a unique $t$-structure on $SH(S)$. 
I am trying to understand the truncation functors $(-)_{\geq d}$ and $(-)_{\leq d}$ on $SH(S)$.

Given a spectrum $E$, can one explicitly describe $E_{\geq d}$ or $E_{\leq d}$ for $d\in \mathbb{Z}$, or for $d=0$ in particular?

I would like to have an intuitive understanding of what $\mathbf{1}_{\leq 0}$ or $H\mathbb{Z}_{\leq 0}$ is, where $\mathbf{1}$ is $\Sigma^\infty S_+$ and $H\mathbb{Z}$ is the motivic Eilenberg-Maclane spectrum.

Can one say more when $S$ is the spectrum of a perfect field? Or even a field of characteristic zero?

Comment: When you mean intuition, are you asking for examples of what their names as algebro-geometric objects (and perhaps an intuitive proof of these results) or are you asking how to think of these objects in an analogous fashion to their counterparts in topology?

Comment: Any connection these objects have with known algebro-geometric objects would be interesting to know. Since I am new to this area, either of the options you give would be a great help for me.